# Increase Jetty performance

Tags: performance, jetty, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have a program that has to make many thousands of http requests as quickly as hardware will allow.  In the real world each of these connections will go to a discrete server, but I have written a test program that will help me simulate a load (hopefully).

My program uses Apache HttpClient to make the http requests.  I based my code on the [Threaded request execution](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientMultiThreadedExecution.java) example from [here](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/examples.html).

My test program is using Jetty to handle the http requests and return a proper response.  I based my code on a simple example like HelloServlet found [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty#Creating_Servlets).

When I run the test and monitor the jetty process it only uses a modest amount of CPU resources.  Furthermore, I used a VM to run a second instance of the jetty server and saw that the test completed in nearly half the time.

I looked for information on how to tune Jetty and found [this document](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/High_Load).  I followed those steps but it did not seem to improve performance.  Is there better documentation on how to increase the performance of Jetty?

### Edit

I instrumented my Jetty server to show me the idle thread count during execution.  I configured the server's threadPool like this:

```
server.setThreadPool(new ExecutorThreadPool(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(500)));
```

But my test program tells me that ~490 threads are idle.  My production code is using 2,000 threads but it seems jetty is queuing the connections.

Comment: What machine do You use CPU, CPU speed, RAM ?

Comment: The jetty server is running on an i5 quad core with 8G RAM.  The UUT is an intel atom with 2G RAM, but the bottleneck seems to be the jetty server.

Comment: Have you found any solution? I am having a similar issue here ... some hints might help ...

Answer (score 3):

The best guidance I can give you is to refer to you a couple of blogs by Greg Wilkins, the founder of jetty about benchmarking.  I say this because honestly trying to tune to your scenario above really does not achieve much of actual interest.

http://webtide.intalio.com/2010/06/lies-damned-lies-and-benchmarks-2/

and

http://webtide.intalio.com/2012/05/truth-in-benchmarking/

I'll also toss out that the primary way to improve servlets right now is to make them asynchronous which seems simple but can bring about a whole host of other programming foibles. Alternately making use of a modern protocol like SPDY or websockets can again massively improve performance in many cases.